# SQL Query to find different city with any city code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with states, and district code.

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nokha | 101 |
| 2 | Nokha | 105 |
| 3 | Bajju | 107 |
| 4 | Bajju | 109 |
| 5 | Byawar | 175 |
| 6 | Bajju | 171 |

Now, I an output something like this

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nokha | 101 |
| 3 | Bajju | 107 |
| 4 | Bajju | 109 |
| 5 | Byawar | 175 |

I mean, I want to have unique city with a code which doesnot get repeated.

So, for your help, I have some code:

```
create table tbl_thana
(
    id   serial not null,
    name varchar,
    code integer
);

alter table tbl_thana
    owner to postgres;

INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (1, 'Nokha', 101);
INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (2, 'Nokha', 105);
INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (3, 'Bajju', 107);
INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (4, 'Bajju', 109);
INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (5, 'Byawar', 175);
INSERT INTO public.tbl_thana (id, name, code) VALUES (6, 'Bajju', 171);
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have assumed this is [[tag:postgresql]] as the above is not valid T-SQL.

Comment: Why u left "Nokha" as u included "Bajju" twice.... I do not understand what you want to do

Comment: @Larnu SQL is SQL!

Comment: *"SQL is SQL!"* The fact that you think this demonstrated the problem further. SQL isn't SQL and every RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL, which all have different syntaxes and functions. They also all support varying amount of ANSI-SQL and thus just because a statement is ANSI-SQL doesn't mean it works on every RDBMS, or every version of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want one record for each state, having some code, possibly the earliest one.  If so, then you may use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) id, name, code
FROM public.tbl_thana
ORDER BY name, code;
```

Note that your expected output has state `Bajju` appearing twice.  This is either a typo, or you have additional rules not stated.